# Scrapy KeyError(f"{self.__class__.__name__} does not support field: {key}"

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

Calling on all Scrapy experts to look into what this newbie missed.

I am getting the following error

```
KeyError(f"{self.__class__.__name__} does not support field: {key}"
```

My code is as follows:

In spiders/myCrawler.py

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['title'] = response.css('.p-card__info-title')
    return item
```

and in my settings.py

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

I am unable to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```py
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['title'] = response.css('.p-card__info-title')
    return item
```

In this you are initializing `scrapy.Item()` instead of your own item

```py
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['title'] = response.css('.p-card__info-title')
    return item
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Of course, I had to import MyItem()